# MVC using different text for form label

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have just created an MVC project and my view looks like this

```
{
    @model Models.LeadModels
    ViewBag.Title = "Add a Lead";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
<h3>@ViewBag.Message</h3>

<p>@ViewBag.SaveResult</p>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "Lead"))
{
    <p>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)</p>
    <p>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.LastName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName)</p>
    <p>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Company)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Company)</p>
    <p>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Province)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Province)</p>
    <p>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Telephone)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Telephone)</p>
    <p>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.EmailAddress)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmailAddress)</p>
    <p>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.LeadStatus)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LeadStatus)</p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Add Lead" /></p>
}
```

When this is rendered the labels are the same as my model properties, as in the text says "FirstName"

Questions.

1. Is there a way to put in a different label (First Name instead of FirstName) using a HTML Helper method?
2. Are there any neat stuff/tricks we can do to change the display? Such as set the labels to be a fixed width so they all line up?
3. Is there a way to use a HTML Helper method to output the submit button? Or do I need to manually write the HTML like I am doing?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to put in a different label (First Name instead of
>   FirstName) using a HTML Helper method?

You can use `Display` attribute data annotation on your property name

```
public class LeadModels
{
  [Display(Name = "First name")]
  public string FirstName { set; get; }
}
```

`LabelFor` helper method will render the value you provided for the Name attribute

> Are there any neat stuff/tricks we can do to change the display? Such
>   as set the labels to be a fixed width so they all line up?

You can use your css classes style the content. You may also consider using bootstrap css classes which does the alignment in a neat way

> Is there a way to use a HTML Helper method to output the submit
>   button? Or do I need to manually write the HTML like I am doing?

No. There is no helper methods for that. You should write your html tag for the button.

Also, in the asp.net core version, tag helpers are available which allows us to write more HTML style code instead of calling the C# methods in view.

Comment: Thank you, quick side question, is there a way to render an asterix for required fields? In my model I have [Required]